# What is this "of" here?

Tags: grammar

Does the criminal justice system need more or less **of** a governmental relationship to be effective?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: It's a partitive genitive construction.

Answer (score 3):

"More or less of" has two meanings in English. One is idiomatic, one is literal.

Idiomatically, it means about, approximately, roughly. or an undetermined amount.

> - To say what the net profits have been, to the entire body of people who have invested money in the telephone, will always be *more or less of* a guess.
> - She smiled blandly at them and then proceeded to hurl what was *more or less of* a bombshell at them.

The literal meaning means *more* or *less* of something.

> - Do you think bullying is *more* or *less* ***of a problem*** now than a decade ago?
> - Comparative adjectives, such as taller and shorter, compare one person or thing with another and enable us to say whether a person or thing has *more* or *less* ***of a particular quality***.

Which of these two meanings your sentence has can be determined by the context it's in.

Comment: So it be rephrased like "something of a guess?"

Comment: @username901345 - I would need to see the paragraph the sentence is in or which follows it to know for sure. It should be apparent by it's context, which I don't have.  If I were a lawyer, I could probably make an accurate educated guess, but I am not. Sorry. :(

Comment: It's pretty clear to me that it's the second option.  No amount of context could change that from _does it need more of X to be Y or does it need less of X to be Y_. It cannot be replaced with _guess_ version.

Comment: @Frank - I lean towards this option as well, but can see it as the first if I squint. Since I don't know for sure, I won't make the call. However, I am glad you did.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, "of" is a preposition in the prepositional phrase "of a governmental relationship." Interestingly, it is the preceding adjectives "more or less" that necessitate the preposition "of." Without the adjectives, the sentence would be perfectly correct and clear without the preposition, "Does the criminal justice system need a governmental relationship to be effective?" I think this basically answers the "what" question, but I expect there is more that can be explained about "why."